# How do I use nextPageToken to download all videos automatically in Swift project?

Tags: ios, video, download, youtube-data-api

In my Swift3 project I have downloaded all 130 videos from YouTube with embedding of YouTubeHelper. I used `"nextPageToken":` 2 times and totally downloaded 3 times by creating 3 `urls`. However, I need to add more pages automatically in the future by checking `nextPageToken`. I searched but didn't find any helpful answer in Swift. Is there any way to download from second page and other pages automatically by checking `nextPageToken`?

My code to download first page:

```
let urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=\(playlistID)&key=\(apiKey)"

let url = URL(string: urlString)

        let session = URLSession.shared

        session.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in


}).resume()
```

Code to download second page:

```
let urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&pageToken="token I got"&playlistId=\(playlistID)&key=\(apiKey)"

let url = URL(string: urlString)

        let session = URLSession.shared

        session.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in


}).resume()
```